# How can I determine a Class's superclass at runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, class

In Actionscript 3, if I'm given a Class object, is there any way to determine if that class extends from another given class?  I don't want to instantiate the class to check it with the `is` keyword, though.

More specifically, I'm trying to make this function work:

```
public function validateClass(classObj:Class):EngineObject{
    if(classObj extends EngineObject){
        return new classObj();
    } else {
        throw new Error("Given class is not a subclass of EngineObject!");
    }
}
```

*Edit: forgot that `in` is reserved in AS3*

Comment: First off, `in` is a reserved word, you can't use it as a variable.

Comment: I would be interested in the use case of this.  It looks like from the answers that it can be done, but what are you looking for that cant be done with an interface?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `flash.utils.getQualifiedSuperclassName()` and `flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName()`

Your function could look like this.

```
import flash.utils.getQualifiedSuperclassName;
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

public function validateClass(cl:Class):EngineObject{
    if(getQualifiedSuperclassName(cl) == getQualifiedClassName(EngineObject) ){
        return new cl();
    } else {
        throw new Error("Given class is not a subclass of EngineObject!");
    }
}
```

But this will only work for a single iteration depth.

You could do this for each iteration step until you are on `object` level. Here a complete approach.

```
public function validateClass(cl:Class):EngineObject
{
    if ( getQualifiedSuperclassName(cl) == getQualifiedClassName(EngineObject) )
    {
        return new cl();
    }

    var sup:Class = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedSuperclassName(cl)) as Class;
    if ( sup == null || getQualifiedSuperclassName(sup) == getQualifiedClassName(Object) )
    {
        throw new Error("Given class is not a subclass of EngineObject!");
    }

    return validateClass(sup);
}
```

Comment: My answer _should_ check every ancestor until Object, but it's not tested

Comment: Was building and testing a complete solution in the meanwhile ;-)

Comment: Is there any performance benefit to using recursion instead of a while loop?

Comment: @shanethehat To be honest, I don't know ;-) It's more a programming style thing. May be your solution is better/quicker than mine, can't say that.

Comment: To be honest I doubt it makes much difference unless we start dealing with hundreds of layers of inheritance. I'm just always curious when I see things done differently in case I need to learn something new :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `describeType` to figure out all of the classes any given type extends from, and a lot of other interesting stuff.

[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29)

`describeType` returns an XML with pretty much everything you'd want to know about a class. All you need to do is loop through all the elements called `extendsClass`, and compare their attribute `type` to a classname of your choice. To figure out the classname, just use `getQualifiedClassName` on the type you're comparing to.

Answer (score 1):

```
function validateClass($class:Class):EngineObject {
    var qn:String = getQualifiedClassName($class);
    var en:String = getQualifiedClassName(EngineObject);
    while(qn != "Object") {
        if(qn == en) return new $class();
        qn = getQualifiedSuperclassName(getDefinitionByName(qn));
    }
    throw new Error("Given class is not a subclass of EngineObject!");
}
```

The idea here is the get the qualified name of the superclass and compare it to the qualified name of `EngineObject`. If this doesn't match, the superclass is set as the new class name, and the loop runs again.  When the qualified superclass name is `Object` you know there are no more ancestors to check.